# MySQL prepared statement with multiple parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I need a search script that has one keyword but will search 2 columns.  How do I use prepared statement that can support that?

```
$key = $_POST['key'];
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM `templates` WHERE `cpt`=? OR `desc`=? ORDER BY `name` cpt");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$key);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $cpt, $desc);
```

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param("ss",$key,$key);` Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Federico I would say `$stmt->bind_param("ss",$key,$key1);`

Comment: @Alex, where you see `$key1`?

Comment: @Federico I don't . But I am pretty sure that there should be 2 different parameters/variables bind. probably `$_POST['desc']`

Comment: You're probably right

Comment: Nah, the first post is right... only one key that will search both column just like stated in the question.